# how to set validation rule for password in prestashop 1.6.3

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

how to set validation rule for password in prestashop 1.6.3
I need  to add validation for alpha numeric and some validation rules.Currently prestashop by default takes any password without any validation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a hook `actionBeforeSubmitAccount`. In that hook you can validate any POST field and pass errors to the controller's error array.

```
public function hookActionBeforeSubmitAccount()
{
    $password = Tools::getValue('passwd');
    // some validation logic here
    if ($some_validation_failed) {
        // Add error to AuthController's errors array
        $this->context->controller->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Password validation failed!');
    }
}
```

The AuthController creates an account only if its property `$errors` array is empty, otherwise it will put you back into account form with errors.

Pretty much every other controller works the same way when it comes to validations.

Answer (score 0):

In file /classes/Validate.php, you will see a function as follows:

```
public static function isPasswd($passwd, $size = Validate::PASSWORD_LENGTH)
{
    return (Tools::strlen($passwd) >= $size && Tools::strlen($passwd) < 255);
}
```

This function is responsible for the current validation of any password, you can simply modify the same as per your requirements.